# Interpolation of 3D Arrays (python)

Tags: python

hopefully, there isn't a similar question. So far, I am quite struggling with interpolating in python two different datasets of arrays to define the z-direction for another.

In other words: this is my original data set, just plotted in 3D space.

[Original data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFZUY.png)

Now I am trying to interpolate the z-values to the original data set (the best solution would be with a "quadratic" polynomial function) with these x/y points (z=0):

[Sought data set with z=0, sought are the new-interpolated z-values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dK4R.png)

Unfortunately, I was only able to illustrate this kind of plot, which doesn't make sense at all:

[My best solution - unfortunately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1abC.png)

Here are my defined arrays, "pla_data.txt" is referred to as the original data; "sof_data.txt" is referred to the desired data:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0eb1957ceae06e8a7ac44d71063d19cc20220113164938/417b2b853840b5019eccd7d68c3df16a20220113164938/cf9729

Hopefully, somebody could help me. Thank you!

Comment: If I understood well what you are trying to achieve (a quadratic polynomial regression), seems like it is not possible to calculate (at least with a decent accuracy) since you have many identical "x_s" in your "desired" data (sof_data.txt) that you want to match for different "x_p" in your "original" data (pla_data.txt). Example: the first 2 rows in sof_data.txt have x_s = 2.5 and the first 2 rows in pla_data.txt have x_p -0.61 and -1.25, just to mention the first 2 rows.

Comment: yes the first part is right! I'll try another way: the z-values for "sof_data.txt" are 0, and I am trying to achive a interpolation of the x_s&y_s values w.r.t. the "pla_data.txt" to interpolate the z_p values for "sof_data.txt". In the end, the "sof_data.txt" should contain almost the same z-values as in "pla_data.txt"; however, it should be quadratic if that is anyhow possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.